# TypeScript declare module for class export

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript1.8, typescript-typings

I'm new to TypeScript and I'm having a problem loading an es6 javascript module.

I have the following javascript file

```
//TemplateFactory.js
export class TemplateFactory{
    static getTemplate(module){

    }
}
```

and I created the following d.ts file

```
//TemplateFactory.d.ts
declare module "TemplateFactory" {
    export class TemplateFactory {
        static getTemplate(module);
    }
}
```

However when I import the js module in another ts file I get this error:

> File ....TemplateFactory .d.ts is not a module

What am I doing wrong? 
I'm using TypeScript 1.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to solve this.
Here is the code that worked for me:

```
export declare class TemplateFactory {
    static getTemplate(module: any): void;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this ,

```
//TemplateFactory.d.ts

declare module TemplateFactory {

    export class TemplateFactory {
        static getTemplate(module);
    }
}
```

Don't use quotes .

Comment: Sorry.. It's not working. I've found the solution and add my own answer